# vim opens my folds on paste. how to prevent that?

Tags: vim, fortran

There's something weird going on in my fortran folding. This is the example file

```
module foo
contains
subroutine hello()

end subroutine hello
subroutine hello()

end subroutine

subroutine hello()

end subroutine
end module foo

subroutine hello()

end subroutine
subroutine hello()

end subroutine
subroutine hello()

end subroutine
```

and this is the vimrc

```
syntax on
au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.f90 setfiletype fortran
set foldmethod=syntax
let fortran_fold=1
```

The annoying thing is the following. If I cut (dd) and paste (P) a folded subroutine *outside* the module/end module block, the freshly pasted fold stay closed. If I paste it *inside* the module/end module block, the newly pasted folded region appears instead unfolded. Can you reproduce the issue (vim 7.2 here) and do you know any workaround/fix ?

Comment: Does `:h 'foldopen'` help? (Not sure).

Comment: @Benoit: No, I think there's some kind of bug in the folding setup for fortran, when something is inside a module, but it's a wild guess.

Comment: I would like to suggest some nnoremapping of `p` with tricky things involving `:.folddoopen` and `:.folddoclosed` but I am not sure this could solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's no specific fortran-module problem but a general one.

There's a [vimtip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text) that provides a solution for accidently opening folds when going to edit a file. The trick is to set the `foldmethod` to `manual` when editing starts:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * if !exists('w:last_fdm') | let w:last_fdm=&foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
```

When you're done with editing (or leave the window), reset `foldmethod` to it's original value:

```
autocmd InsertLeave,WinLeave * if exists('w:last_fdm') | let &l:foldmethod=w:last_fdm | unlet w:last_fdm | endif
```

Comment: do you know an event to make the same changes before and after pressing `p` or `P`, that is a put of text?